# What is the global maximum of $x^{1/x}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, optimization

Let the following function be defined as such:
$$F_x: \Bbb R \to \Bbb C, x \mapsto x^{1/x}, \forall x \ne 0$$

What I want to know is 
$$\max_{x<0}\Re\left(F_x\right)=\,?$$
and
$$\max_{x<0}\Im\left(F_x\right)=\,?$$

---

**Additional Questions**

- Why does $F$ act weird when approaching $0$ form the left? For example $$\lim_{x\to0^-}F_x=\infty \text{ and }\lim_{x\to0^+}F_x=0$$
- What is with the oscillation when approaching?
- How are $\Re(F_x)$ and $\Im(F_x)$ related during the left approach?
- Are there any other functions with similar behaviors?

Comment: It seems for $x < 0$, you define $\operatorname{Sr}(x) = \exp(\frac1x(\log \lvert x\rvert + \pi i))$?

Comment: Is there even a total order in $\operatorname{Sr}[\Bbb R]$?

Comment: Could you clarify.  You are mapping the real numbers into the complex plane.  But I don't understand what complex values you produce.  f(x) = x^(1/x) only gives real values. I thought you might mean f(z) = z^(1/z) but that maps complex into complex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $x\gt0$, we have
$$
x^{1/x}=e^{\log(x)/x}
$$
As $x\to0^+$, $\log(x)/x\to-\infty$.
As $x\to+\infty$, $\log(x)/x\to0$.
In between, $\log(x)/x$ has a maximum of $1/e$ at $x=e$. We get this by looking at its derivative, which is $\frac{1-\log(x)}{x^2}$.

Therefore, for $x\gt0$, we have an infimum of $0$ as $x\to0^+$ and a maximum of $e^{1/e}$ at $x=e$.

---

For $x\lt0$, let $x=-t$. Then, taking $\log(x)=\log(-t)=\log(t)+i\pi$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
x^{1/x}
&=e^{-(\log(t)+i\pi)/t}\\
&=(\cos(\pi/t)-i\sin(\pi/t))e^{-\log(t)/t}
\end{align}
$$
As $t\to0^+$ (that is, $x\to0^-$), $-\log(t)/t\to+\infty$.
As $t\to+\infty$ (that is $x\to-\infty$), $-\log(t)/t\to0$.
In between, $-\log(t)/t$ has a minimum of $-1/e$ at $t=e$.

Therefore, for $t>0$, $e^{-\log(t)/t}$ have a minimum of $e^{-1/e}$ at $t=e$ and a supremum of $+\infty$ as $t\to0^+$.

However, since
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Re}\left(x^{1/x}\right)&=\hphantom{-}\cos(\pi/t)e^{-\log(t)/t}\\
\mathrm{Im}\left(x^{1/x}\right)&=-\sin(\pi/t)e^{-\log(t)/t}
\end{align}
$$
the fact that $e^{-\log(t)/t}$ grows without bound and the $\sin(\pi/t)$ and $\cos(\pi/t)$ oscillate faster and faster between $+1$ and $-1$ as $t\to0^+$ means that
$$
\begin{align}
\limsup_{x\to0^-}\mathrm{Re}\left(x^{1/x}\right)
&=\limsup_{x\to0^-}\mathrm{Im}\left(x^{1/x}\right)=+\infty\\
\liminf_{x\to0^-}\mathrm{Re}\left(x^{1/x}\right)
&=\liminf_{x\to0^-}\mathrm{Im}\left(x^{1/x}\right)=-\infty\\
\end{align}
$$
which in turn imply
$$
\bbox[5px, border: 1px solid #C00000]{
\begin{align}
\sup_{x\lt0}\mathrm{Re}\left(x^{1/x}\right)
&=\sup_{x\lt0}\mathrm{Im}\left(x^{1/x}\right)=+\infty\\
\inf_{x\lt0}\mathrm{Re}\left(x^{1/x}\right)
&=\inf_{x\lt0}\mathrm{Im}\left(x^{1/x}\right)=-\infty\\
\end{align}
}
$$

---

Plots of $\mathrm{Re}\left(x^{1/x}\right)$ and $\mathrm{Im}\left(x^{1/x}\right)$:

$\hspace{3.2cm}$[image]

$\hspace{3.2cm}$[image]

---

**Additional Answers**

$\ \small\bullet$ The weird behavior when approaching $0$ from the left is two-fold:

First, for $x\lt0$, $\log(|x|)/x\to+\infty$ as $x\to0^-$; therefore, $\left|\,x^{1/x}\,\right|=e^{\log(|x|)/x}\to+\infty$.

Second, due to the $\pi i$ in $\log(x)$ for $x\lt0$, $\arg\left(x^{1/x}\right)=\pi/x$ forces both real and imaginary parts to oscillate positive and negative.

$\ \small\bullet$ For $x\lt0$, $\mathrm{Re}\left(x^{1/x}\right)^2+\mathrm{Im}\left(x^{1/x}\right)^2=e^{\log(|x|)/x}$ and $\frac{\displaystyle\mathrm{Im}\left(x^{1/x}\right)}{\displaystyle\mathrm{Re}\left(x^{1/x}\right)}=\tan(\pi/x)$.

Comment: Just to note. Because of the chain rule the derivative is product the original function and the derivative you stated.

Comment: @Alizter: We are looking for the maximum of $\log(x)/x$, and its derivative is $\frac{1-\log(x)}{x^2}$. I have edited that passage to make this clearer.

Comment: Oh sorry. I see what you mean now.

Comment: robjohn Thank you for such a detailed analysis of my question. I really do appreciate the effort that has gone into this. You have done an excellent job of breaking down the problem and explaining it and for that I shall reward you the bounty of 50 reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. Now for those real values.

For x → 0 you have two cases: one is where the function has real values.  If you look at x values like -1/n Sr(-1/n) = (-1/n)<sup>-n</sup> = ± 1/n<sup>n</sup> which in absolute value → 0.  You'll get the same result with any sequence of x → 0<sup>-</sup> for which Sr(x) is real.

Now the case where Sr(x) is complex. Consider for example x = -8/9.  (-8/9)<sup>-9/8</sup> = (8/9)<sup>-9/8</sup>(-1)<sup>-9/8</sup>.  The roots of -1 are all on the unit circle, so the absolute value cannot exceed |(-8/9)<sup>-9/8</sup>| =(9/8)<sup>9/8</sup>, but it could be close if the root you pick has absolute value near 1. Consider |Sr(-4/9)| is near (9/4)<sup>9/4</sup>, a larger base and a larger exponent.  Since the variance in the absolute value of the roots closest to 1 should be small, it looks as if this kind of sequence will → ∞ You have a few things to nail down to formalize this.  Once that is done you can trap other sequences with complex Sr within the sequences you know are → ∞.

However, you've got the problem that some of the subsequences are real and go to zero.  So I would say that generally you do not have a limit.  If you want the ∞ limit, you are going to have to restrict yourself to sequences where Sr(x) is complex.

You have I think an additional problem, which is that if you pick the zeros of (-1) whose absolute values are closest to 0, the |Sr| may not → ∞.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The question has had a complete make over! Sorry about the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if im wrong, but is this not Steiner's problem concering the Euler number?

He found it using an inequality, $e^{(x-e)/e} \geq 1 + \dfrac{x-e}{e}$.

Comment: The question has had a complete make over! Sorry about the inconvenience.