# differentiate the xth root of x

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find the maximum of $x^{1/x}$. I don't know how to find the derivative of this. I have plugged in some numbers and found that $e^{1/e}$ seems to be the maximum at around 1.44466786. I don't know if this is the maximum, and I would like an explanation of why it is/what the maximum is. essentially, how do I solve ${{dy}\over{dx}}(x^{1/x})=0$?

Comment: Set $q=x$ and $s=1/x$. Apply the multivariable chain rule to $z=q^s$: ${dz\over dx}={\partial z\over\partial q}\cdot{dq\over dx}+{\partial z\over\partial s}\cdot{ds\over dx}$.

Comment: Basically the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1726540) (roughly equal quality answers). Also see [an older post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464510).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=x^{1/x}$. If you add natural log to both sides, then you have $\ln y=\ln x^{1/x}$, or more importantly, $$\ln y = \frac 1x \ln x$$
You can now differentiate implicitly both sides to get (use product rule on RHS) $$\frac 1y \frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac 1{x^2}\ln x+\frac 1{x^2}$$
Multiply both sides by $y$ to get $\frac{dy}{dx}$ by itself. And replace that $y=x^x$. Simplify wherever possible. Then you can set the derivative equal to zero and find the critical $x$ value that will give you the minimum of $y$.

Comment: Why not go one step further: $\ln$ is an increasing function, thus maximizing $x^{1/x}$ is the same as maximizing $f(x)=\ln(x^{1/x})=\ln(x)/x$. That avoids the clutter on the left side of the equation.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^{\frac{1}{x}}=e^{\ln{x^{\frac{1}{x}}}}=e^{\frac{1}{x} \ln x}$$

Can you find now the derivative?

Answer (score 0):

$$y=x^{1/x}\implies \ln(y)=\frac{\ln x}x$$

$$\frac{d(\ln y)}{dx}=\frac{d(\ln y)}{dy}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac1y\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}$$

and $$\frac{d\left(\frac{\ln x}x\right)}{dx}=\frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to rewrite $$x^{1/x}$$ as $$e^{\ln x \over x}$$
and then differentiate using the chain rule.