# How to differentiate $x^{\frac1x}$?

Tags: derivatives, exponentiation

How should $x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ be differentiated? I know the answer is 
$$\frac{1-\ln(x)}{x^{2-\frac{1}{x}}}$$

but I do not understand how to get there.

### Attempt at solution.

I believe the following is true:

$$
\begin{aligned}\frac{d}{dx}x^u&=ux^{u-1}\cdot u^\prime\\
\frac{d}{dx}a^x&=a^x\cdot\ln(a)
\end{aligned}$$
but I don't know what to do when both the base and the exponent are functions of $x$.

Comment: Hint $x^{1/x}=e^{\frac1x \ln x}$

Comment: First, I would use the word "differentiate" here rather than "derive" since has a completely different meaning.  Second, write ln(y)= ln(x)/x and use the quotient rule on the right side and the chain rule on the left side.

Comment: Basically the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1206195) (roughly equal quality answers). Also see [an older post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464510).

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**
 Let $y=x^{1/x}$. Now take the natural log of both sides.
$$\ln(y)=\ln(x^{1/x})=\frac{1}{x}\ln(x).$$ Now you can differentiate both sides and solve to find $y'$. I'll even do the left side for you:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln(y)=\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{y'}{x^{1/x}}.$$

Comment: Is $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(y)=\frac{y^\prime}{y}$ an identity?

Comment: @user289661: It's an application of the chain rule.  Let $u = \ln y$, then $\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{du}{dy} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{y} \cdot y' = \frac{y'}{y}$.

Answer (score 2):

$x^{\frac{1}{x}} = e^{\frac{1}{x} ln(x)}$ therefore $\left(x^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)' =  \left(e^{\frac{1}{x} ln(x)}\right)' = e^{\frac{1}{x} ln(x)}\left(\frac{1}{x} ln(x)\right)' = e^{\frac{1}{x} ln(x)} \left(\frac{-1}{x^2}ln(x) + \frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{x}\right) = e^{\frac{1}{x} ln(x)}\left(\frac{1-ln(x)}{x^2}\right) = x^{\frac{1}{x}}x^{-2}\left(1-ln(x)\right) = \frac{\left(1-ln(x)\right)}{x^{2 - \frac{1}{x}}}$

Answer (score 1):

Use the general definition of a *real* exponent:
$$x^{\tfrac1x}\overset{\text{def}}{=}\mathrm e^{\tfrac{\ln x}{x}}.$$
Hence
$$\Bigl(x^{\tfrac1x}\Bigr)'=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{\ln x}{x}}\cdot\frac{\cfrac1x\cdot x-\ln x}{x^2}=x^{\tfrac1x}\cdot\frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

its very simple to get answer

Let $u=x^{\frac{1}{x}}$

take logarithm of both sides

$log\ u=log(x^{\frac{1}{x}})$

$log\ u=\frac{1}{x}log(x)$

differentiation wrt 'x'
$$\frac{d}{dx}log\ u=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{x}log(x)$$
$$to\ differentiate\ this,\ use\ chain\ rule\ in\ LHS\ and\ product\ rule\ in\ RHS$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{u}\cdot \frac{du}{dx}=\frac{1}{x} \cdot \frac{d}{dx}(log\ x)+(log\ x) \cdot \frac{d}{dx}\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{u}\cdot \frac{du}{dx}=\frac{1}{x} \cdot \frac{1}{x}+log\ x\Big(\frac{-1}{x^2}\Big)$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{u}\cdot \frac{du}{dx}=\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{log\ x}{x^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{u}\cdot \frac{du}{dx}=\frac{1}{x^2}\Big[1-log\ x\Big]$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{du}{dx}=u \cdot \frac{1}{x^2}\Big[1-log\ x\Big]$$
Put $$u=x^{\frac{1}{x}}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}\big(x^{\frac{1}{x}}\big)=x^{\frac{1}{x}} \cdot \frac{1}{x^2}\Big[1-log\ x\Big]$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}\big(x^{\frac{1}{x}}\big)=x^{\frac{1}{x}-2}\Big[1-log\ x\Big]$$

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice trick that can rescue you: differentiate all the functions obtained by considering all instances of $x$ but one as constants, and take the sum.

This gives ($X$ is a constant)

$$\left(x^{1/X}\right)'=\frac1Xx^{1/X-1}$$
and
$$\left(X^{1/x}\right)'=\ln X\left(\frac1x\right)'X^{1/x}=-\ln X\frac{X^{1/x}}{x^2}.$$

Then restoring the variable and regrouping,

$$\left(x^{1/x}\right)'=\frac1xx^{1/x-1}-\ln x\frac{x^{1/x}}{x^2}=(1-\ln x)x^{1/x-2}.$$

---

Alternatively, if you are familiar with functions of several variables, you can replace the occurrences of $x$ by independent variables and work with total differentials.

$$x^{1/x}\to z^{1/y},$$ then

$$d\left(z^{1/y}\right)=\frac1yz^{1/y-1}\,dz-\ln z\frac{z^{1/y}}{y^2}\,dy.$$

Now you can evaluate the differential at $x=z=y$, and

$$d\left(x^{1/x}\right)=(1-\ln x)\frac{x^{1/x-2}}{x^2}\,dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

As there is a rule for the sum and product, there is a rule for powers:

$$\left(u^v\right)'=\left(e^{v\ln u}\right)'=(v\ln u)'e^{v\ln u}=(u'v+v'u\ln u)u^{v-1}.$$