# How can I judge the series is convergence or divergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I judge the series is convergence or divergence?
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\Big({n}^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\Big)}^{n}$$

I don't know how to estimate ${n}^{\frac{1}{n}}-1$ when $n→∞$

Comment: Try using the natural log. I assume you're using the divergence test?

Answer (score 1):

Here $$n^{\frac{1}{n}}-1=(e^{\frac{\log n}{n}}-1) \longrightarrow 0$$ since exponential function is continuous and $\frac{\log n}{n} $ tend to zero. So by root test, $$\limsup_{n \to \infty}\Big[(n^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)^n\Big]^{\frac{1}{n}}=\limsup_{n \to \infty} (n^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)=0<1$$

which shows your series converges!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: As the maximum value of $n^{\frac{1}{n}} < 1.5$ (max value of $x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ occures in $x = e$ for $x \geq 1$), we have $(n^{\frac{1}{n}} - 1) ^ n \leq \frac{1}{2^n}$. So it is convergent.

Comment: Just in case, one can see this [related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464510).

Answer (score 0):

To address your question how to estimate ${n}^{\frac{1}{n}}-1$, here is a standard way using only the binomial formula:

- For $x> 0$ and $n\geq 2$ you have $$(1+x)^n = 1 + nx +\color{blue}{\frac{n(n-1)}{2} x^2} + \cdots + x^n > \color{blue}{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2}$$
- It follows 
  $$n = \left(\sqrt[n]{n}\right)^n = \left(1 + \left(\sqrt[n]{n}-1\right)\right)^n > \color{blue}{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\left(\sqrt[n]{n}-1\right)^2}$$

Hence for $n>1$ you get
$$0< \sqrt[n]{n}-1 < \sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}}\stackrel{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$

Now, the convergence of the series follows by the root test.